# 8] Undefined property: Zipcheck::$_html

Tags: php, prestashop

> 8] Undefined property: Zipcheck::$_html

Following is the func

```
private function _displayForm()
    {
        $this->_html .= '<form method="post" name="f" id="f" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="'.Tools::safeOutput($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).'" ">
                          <link href="../modules/zipcheck/views/css/admin-zipcheck.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
                          <script src="../modules/zipcheck/views/js/zipcheck.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <div id="market-form">
                                <div class=""><nav><ul class="nav" >                       
                       <li class="marketmenu"><p class="marketmenu">'.$this->l('Setting').'</p><ul> <li> <input type="submit" name="codcost"  class="marketsubmenu" style="display:block;" value="'.$this->l('COD Settings').'" class="button" /></li></ul></li>
                       <li class="marketmenu"><p class="marketmenu">'.$this->l('Zipcode').'</p><ul >
                       <li>  <input type="submit" name="manageship"  class="marketsubmenu" style="display:block;" value="'.$this->l('Manage Zipcode').'" class="button" /></li>
                       <li>  <input type="submit" name="importshipping"  class="marketsubmenu" style="display:block;" value="'.$this->l('Import Zipcode').'" class="button" /></li>
                       <li>  <input type="submit" name="exportshipping" class="marketsubmenu" value="'.$this->l('Export Zipcode').'" class="button" /></li>                        
                      </ul></li>
                        <li class="marketmenu"><p class="marketmenu">'.$this->l('Product-ZipCode').'</p><ul> <li> <input type="submit" name="prod_zip"  class="marketsubmenu" style="display:block;" value="'.$this->l('Configure Product-Zip').'"  class="button" /></li>
                       <li><input type="submit" name="pzimportshipping"  class="marketsubmenu" style="display:block;" value="'.$this->l('Import Prod-Zip Comb').'" class="button" /></li>
                       <li>  <input type="submit" name="pzexportshipping" class="marketsubmenu" value="'.$this->l('Export Prod-Zip Comb').'" class="button" /></li>                         
                        </ul></li>                    
                      </ul></nav></div></br>';
```

I get a notice from my prestashop module named zipcheck, can somebody help e with this

Answer (score 1):

Try to initialise the variable before the function

```
private $_html = '';
```